# foreign keys redundancy

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, rdbms

I have three tables.

#### user

```
CREATE TABLE user(
    userid INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(userid),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

#### article

```
CREATE TABLE article(
    userid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    subid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    content VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(userid,subid),
    FOREIGN KEY article_user(userid) REFERENCES user(userid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

#### photo

```
CREATE TABLE photo(
    userid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    subid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    articleid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(userid,subid),
    FOREIGN KEY photo_article(userid,articleid) REFERENCES article(userid,subid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Do I need to add a foreign key referencing `userid` between tables `photo` and `user` since `userid` is already referenced within the `photo_article` and `article_user` composite foreign keys? Why?

Comment: Are you sure your use of subid, and articleid are what you want? For each table, when a row is in it what does it say in terms of its columns?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Your `photo_article` foreign key only enforces integrity between `photo` and `article`. It does not enforce integrity for `user`.

You also don't have a foreign key between `user` and `article`.

This means if you have the following data:

### user

```
userid | name | time
-------|------|-----------------
1      | foo  | 1970-01-01 10:00
3      | bar  | 1970-01-01 12:00
```

### article

```
userid | subid | content | time
-------|-------|---------|-----------------
1      | 1     | lorem   | 1970-01-01 10:15
2      | 2     | ipsum   | 1970-01-01 11:15
3      | 3     | dolor   | 1970-01-01 12:15
```

### photo

```
userid | subid | articleid | name | time
-------|-------|-----------|------|-----------------
1      | 1     | 1         | foo  | 1970-01-01 10:30
2      | 2     | 2         | bar  | 1970-01-01 11:30
```

This data will be valid, even though `userid` 2 does not exist in users (assuming there is a `userid` 2 in `profiles`).

Comment: *You also don't have a foreign key between user and article.*. No, I do have one.

Comment: You didn't include that in your question. If you do have a foreign key between `article` and `user` then you don't need one between `photo` and `user`. It would still be better to explicitly create the foreign key, rather than relying on a link between 2 other tables.

Comment: The foreign key is actually specified in the `syntax`. BTW, why is it better to define another foreign key? Just because I found [this article](https://rodgersnotes.wordpress.com/2010/09/18/redundant-foreign-key/) claimimg that it's redundant?

Comment: I meant better in terms of clarity for developers but as I say it's not needed if you have a foreign key set on `article`. I must be missing something... The foreign key on your `article` table references `profile` table not `user`.

Comment: I'm sorry about that typo. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't *necessary*. A `FOREIGN KEY` declaration says that a subrow in a referencing table must also appear as a unique subrow in a referenced table. Enforcing the ones that you declared will enforce the one that you didn't.

But you might or might not want to declare it. Likely, not. The meaning of each row in `photo` is something like "the `subid` photo of user `serid` appears in their `articleid` article". If you ever change the meaning of tables `article` or `user` then it should be understood as part of RDBMS management that (among other things) any foreign keys referencing them directly or transitively may also need change.

There's always an engineering tradeoff between how explicit vs how concise to be and whether a redundancy is positive and/or negative for the present and/or under possible changes.